# Node.js factory function for axios redis dependency injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a `node` `express` app that is making calls to an external API using `axios`. I'm using `redis` for caching. It works fine, but I ran into a number of problems with unit tests - specifically trying to mock or inject mocks for `redis` client and an `axios` instance

My approach to making the route testable was to create a factory function for the route. It works, but I am unsure **if there might be side/adverse effects**, or if I'm using a **bad practice** and missing a standard solution

In `api.js` I require the `details-route`, passing in the `axiosInstance` and `redisClient` instance

```
// api.js
const detailsRouter = require('./details-route')(axiosInstance, redisClient);

router.use('/details', detailsRouter );

module.exports = router;
```

```
//details-route.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fp = require('lodash/fp');
// local modules
const constants = require('../constants');
const axiosUtil = require('../axios-util');

const getRouter = (axiosInstance, redisClient) => {
    router.get('/details', (req, res) => {
        redisClient.get(req.originalUrl, (err, reply) => {
            if (reply) {
               // etc
            }
            // etc
         }
    }
    return router;
}

module.exports = getRouter;
```

Note: I'm using `redis-mock` and `axios-mock-adapter` in my unit tests, and I've looked into using `rewire` (but it's not workable for wrapping the internal redis client)

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Bergi Im thinking the `const router = express.Router();` should probably be declared inside the returned function, rather than at the top level. In tests this might get called multiple times

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea - or even make it an argument of the function as well.